# Bootstrap flash alert CSS not working correctly in mobile screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently building a Rails app. In my app, I show flash message using Bootstrap's CSS on alert. I am not fully using Bootstrap's CSS but adding only related to alert in my app due to overlap in CSS.

CSS for flash works fine for normal desktop screen. It's position is centered and fixed. Image below:

[image]

However, when I populate the flash on mobile screen (lesser than 500px), then it is off-centered to left no matter what I do. Image below:
[image]

I am confused why this is happening. Just like the descktop screen, I would like to fix the position of flash in mobile screen and always populate on a same place.

Following is the view code I have for the flash

```
<div id="flash-message-wrapper">
    <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
        <div class="alert <%= alert_class_for(type) %> alert-dismissible fade in">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
            </button>
            <%= message %>
     <% end %>
</div>
```

The CSS for this code is :

```
.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.alert h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: inherit;
}
.alert .alert-link {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.alert > p,
.alert > ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.alert > p + p {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.alert-dismissable,
.alert-dismissible {
  padding-right: 35px;
}

.alert-dismissable .close,
.alert-dismissible .close {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  right: -21px;
  color: inherit;
}
.alert-success {
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.alert-success hr {
  border-top-color: #c9e2b3;
}
.alert-success .alert-link {
  color: #2b542c;
}
.alert-info {
  color: #31708f;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
}
.alert-info hr {
  border-top-color: #a6e1ec;
}
.alert-info .alert-link {
  color: #245269;
}
.alert-warning {
  color: #8a6d3b;
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border-color: #faebcc;
}
.alert-warning hr {
  border-top-color: #f7e1b5;
}
.alert-warning .alert-link {
  color: #66512c;
}
.alert-danger {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
}
.alert-danger hr {
  border-top-color: #e4b9c0;
}
.alert-danger .alert-link {
  color: #843534;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
       -o-transition: opacity .15s linear;
          transition: opacity .15s linear;
}
.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  filter: alpha(opacity=20);
  opacity: .2;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}
button.close {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 0;
}
.sr-only-focusable:active,
.sr-only-focusable:focus {
  position: static;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  clip: auto;
}

#flash-message-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -250px;
    width: 600px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #flash-message-wrapper {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50px;
            right: 50%;
            margin-right: -250px;
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the style of `#flash-message-wrapper` to this

```
#flash-message-wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  #flash-message-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  }
}
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pe4ad6yy/1/). Hope this helps.

> Update

If you want to hover your notification you need to add these following properties to your existing styles.

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pe4ad6yy/2/).

Comment: Try resizing the preview pane to see the effect.

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't hover over the elements I have. This code will push down my whole view which I do not want.

Comment: See the update. Let me know if that does the work for you.